# Django query to check if object date lies in between start date and end date of another queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models and both have foreign keys with the User model:

```
class UserCostCenter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost_center = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class UserBooking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    hours = models.DecimalField()
    task = models.ForeignKey(UserProject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords(table_name='booking_history_userbooking')
```

Now I want to exclude the userbookings which does not have a cost center
Currently I am doing like this:

```
    queryset = UserBooking.objects.all()
    for booking in queryset:
        cost_center = UserCostCenter.objects.filter(
        Q(user=booking.user, start_date__lte=booking.date, end_date__gte=booking.date)
        | Q(user=booking.user, start_date__lte=booking.date,
            end_date=None)).first()
        if not cost_center:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(id=booking.id)
```

I do not want to exclude userbooking objects using for loop, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all UserBookings with a record in UserCostCenter like this:

```
UserBooking.objects.filter(user__in=(UserCostCenter.objects.values_list('user', flat=True)))
```

Comment: I tried this but did not get expected result. I want a queryset which returns UserBooking objects whose dates fall between the start date and end date of a cost center, else if the object's date does not fall between start and end date of a cost center, then exclude it.

Comment: UserBooking.objects.filter(date__in_between=(UserCostCenter.objects.values_list('start_date', 'end_date')))

Comment: Something like the above queryset

Comment: I think you need to change your model and create a foreignkey between UserBooking and UserCostCenter. A ManytoMany relation. That way its posible to get a queryset without loop